# Kibana3 cloudwatch dashboard not connecting to Elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, cloudwatch

I'm using the tutorial specified in this:
https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer

I did not use a cloudformation template as I already have an ES cluster with Kibana running.
I copied the dashboards in cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer-1.2.0/configuration/kibana/* 
to /var/www/html/app/kibana/app/dashboards/

I am moving from a logstash ELK stack and the logstash.json dashboard works and connects to my ES cluster but the ones from cloudwatch-logs-subscription does not. It gives me a "Connection Failed" along with the http.cors.enabled etc which I have already have in my ES config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. I had 90 gigs of logs on each cluster and was a bit too much to handle.

Though now I need to piece together how to actually grab from cloudwatch logs and send to elasticsearch.